# Serializing BufferedImage by Java Advanced Imaging API JAI

Tags: serialization, bufferedimage, jai

I have a `BufferedImage` object in my hands and I want to serialize this object faster than java imageio by using JAI. However, I could not find any example. Also, I have read the documentation and I have lost in it. After serialization, I want to send the serialized object to another computer and then display this serialized object as picture in the client's monitor. Summarily, I would like only to serialize and deserialize a `BufferedImage` by using JAI. I can handle the other stuff.